# How to aggregate a column based on another - excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using excel 2013 to try to make a chart like this:

[image: bar-line]

with this data (tried to do some formatting on it):

<kbd>Date</kbd>                <kbd>Time</kbd>           <kbd>name</kbd>         <kbd>num1</kbd>        <kbd>num2</kbd>

<kbd>07.28.2014</kbd>       <kbd>7:00 AM</kbd>     <kbd>Joe</kbd>     <kbd>62369</kbd>        <kbd>486</kbd> 
   <kbd>01.10.2015</kbd>       <kbd>1:00 AM</kbd>     <kbd>Joe</kbd>     <kbd>8584</kbd>        <kbd>432</kbd> 
   <kbd>05.01.2014</kbd>       <kbd>3:00 PM</kbd>     <kbd>Jeff</kbd>        <kbd>53199</kbd>        <kbd>204</kbd> 
   <kbd>01.10.2015</kbd>       <kbd>3:00 AM</kbd>     <kbd>Mary</kbd>         <kbd>11505</kbd>        <kbd>465</kbd> 
   <kbd>07.28.2014</kbd>       <kbd>7:00 AM</kbd>     <kbd>Sue</kbd>     <kbd>40332</kbd>        <kbd>267</kbd> 
   <kbd>05.01.2014</kbd>       <kbd>9:00 PM</kbd>     <kbd>Jeff</kbd>         <kbd>21210</kbd>        <kbd>603</kbd> 
   <kbd>01.10.2015</kbd>       <kbd>7:00 PM</kbd>     <kbd>Sue</kbd>     <kbd>48502</kbd>        <kbd>450</kbd> 
   <kbd>05.01.2014</kbd>       <kbd>5:00 AM</kbd>     <kbd>Mary</kbd>         <kbd>34624</kbd>        <kbd>334</kbd> 
   <kbd>04.20.2014</kbd>       <kbd>2:00 PM</kbd>     <kbd>Joe</kbd>     <kbd>67825</kbd>        <kbd>657</kbd> 
   <kbd>01.10.2015</kbd>       <kbd>2:00 AM</kbd>     <kbd>Mary</kbd>         <kbd>28492</kbd>        <kbd>441</kbd> 
   <kbd>01.10.2015</kbd>       <kbd>6:00 PM</kbd>     <kbd>Jeff</kbd>         <kbd>71469</kbd>        <kbd>245</kbd> 
   <kbd>09.06.2014</kbd>       <kbd>12:00 AM</kbd>         <kbd>Mary</kbd>         <kbd>50232</kbd>        <kbd>831</kbd> 
   <kbd>07.28.2014</kbd>       <kbd>5:00 PM</kbd>     <kbd>Sue</kbd>     <kbd>97049</kbd>        <kbd>978</kbd>

(Raw data from table in case you want to play with it):

```
Date    Time    name    num1    num2
07.28.2014  7:00 AM Joe 62369   486
01.10.2015  1:00 AM Joe 8584    432
05.01.2014  3:00 PM Jeff    53199   204
01.10.2015  3:00 AM Mary    11505   465
07.28.2014  7:00 AM Sue 40332   267
05.01.2014  9:00 PM Jeff    21210   603
01.10.2015  7:00 PM Sue 48502   450
05.01.2014  5:00 AM Mary    34624   334
04.20.2014  2:00 PM Joe 67825   657
01.10.2015  2:00 AM Mary    28492   441
01.10.2015  6:00 PM Jeff    71469   245
09.06.2014  12:00 AM    Mary    50232   831
07.28.2014  5:00 PM Sue 97049   978
```

My question is:

How can I aggregate Column A together based on day? I don't know how to build the chart either, but I think I need to aggregate first. My x-axis would be the day, my y-axis for the bar would be num1, and for the line it would be num2 (which would contain sums of the day regardless of time).

I have looked into the aggregate function, but I'm not sure how to plug in things correctly.

Comment: You may want to look into Pivot Tables and Pivot charts to do aggregate type analysis on the fly.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Honestly, I guess it doesn't need to be done on the fly. I'm only using excel as an example for web development.